# Rails 4 gmaps4rails - How to include a link to a "show" view in marker infowindow in gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I have gotten gmaps4rails working in my rails 4 app, with markers for my lcoation, and I would like to include a link in each location's marker to each location's individual show view.

My spaces controller index action looks like this:

```
def index
    @spaces = Space.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@spaces) do |space, marker|
      marker.lat space.latitude
      marker.lng space.longitude
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/spaces/infowindow", :locals => { :object=> space})
    end
end
```

My infowindow partial is:

```
<%= link_to "Show", space_path(space) %>
```

My gmaps4rails javascript script in my spaces/index.html view is:

```
<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
</script>
```

When I try to load my spaces index page I am greeted with the following error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `space' for #<#<Class:0x4638c48>:0x5335f20>
```

Based on my previous searches this seems to be the way to get a link working in a marker's infowindow but if there is an alternative solution I would love to hear it, thank you.

Comment: You can move the UPDATE part out into an answer to this question and accept your own question. In this way your question won't pop up as unsolved and people can upvote on your answer, if they like! :)

Comment: Please don't put an answer in the question; post your solution as an answer post below instead. I've removed your edit from the question post.

Answer (score 1):

**Originally posted by the OP in the question itself**

spaces controller index action should looks like this :

```
def index
    @spaces = Space.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@spaces) do |space, marker|
      marker.lat space.latitude
      marker.lng space.longitude
      marker.json({:id => space.id })
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/spaces/infowindow", :locals => { :object => space})
    end
end
```

and partial view should looks like this:

```
<%= link_to 'See Space', space_path(object) %>
```

---

Comment: if you are going to do that, better make the post a *community wiki* post, and add a note that this was taken from the OP's post. See [Best way to deal with questions answered by the OP in the question instead of in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108969). I've converted this post now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you very much.